# Ruby on Rails image loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, loops

I'm attempting to create a loop which shows stars as reviews are placed for a product, i have it so that it shows the rating as a number however i wish for it to display an image relating to the rating number,

i've currently got

```
<%=product.no_of_stars.to_i do image_tag "star-on.png" end %>
```

however it just displays the rating figure and not the number, no doubt I've missed something simple.

I've researched other questions and they state that should be enough for what i want, but of course its not working as expected.

Thanks, Ben.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above answer is not quite correct. The problem is that Integer#times returns the integer it was called on, so you will still get 5 as the result. Try

```
<% product.no_of_starts.to_i.times do %>
  <%= image_tag "star-on.png" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Good call. I didn't think of the multiple lines that would be needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<%=product.no_of_stars.to_i.times do image_tag "star-on.png" end %>
```

You are missing the `times` method. This is what allows you to run the number as a loop over and over again (super simplification).